# What is the parent linux image of golang:1.7

Tags: docker

On doing

```
$ docker history --no-trunc golang:1.7
```

it gives the output:

```
/bin/sh -c #(nop) COPY file:f6191f2c86edc9343569339f101facba47e886e33e29d70da6916ca6b1101a53 in /usr/local/bin/                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          2.48kB              
/bin/sh -c #(nop) WORKDIR /go                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            0B                  
/bin/sh -c mkdir -p "$GOPATH/src" "$GOPATH/bin" && chmod -R 777 "$GOPATH"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                0B                  
/bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV PATH=/go/bin:/usr/local/go/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       0B                  
/bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV GOPATH=/go                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        0B                  
/bin/sh -c set -eux;   dpkgArch="$(dpkg --print-architecture)";  case "${dpkgArch##*-}" in   amd64) goRelArch='linux-amd64'; goRelSha256='ad5808bf42b014c22dd7646458f631385003049ded0bb6af2efc7f1f79fa29ea' ;;   armhf) goRelArch='linux-armv6l'; goRelSha256='fc5c40fb1f76d0978504b94cd06b5ea6e0e216ba1d494060d081e022540900f8' ;;   i386) goRelArch='linux-386'; goRelSha256='99f79d4e0f966f492794963ecbf4b08c16a9a268f2c09053a5ce10b343ee4082' ;;   ppc64el) goRelArch='linux-ppc64le'; goRelSha256='8b5b602958396f165a3547a1308ab91ae3f2ad8ecb56063571a37aadc2df2332' ;;   s390x) goRelArch='linux-s390x'; goRelSha256='d692643d1ac4f4dea8fb6d949ffa750e974e63ff0ee6ca2a7c38fc7c90da8b5b' ;;   *) goRelArch='src'; goRelSha256='1a67a4e688673fdff7ba41e73482b0e59ac5bd0f7acf703bc6d50cc775c5baba';    echo >&2; echo >&2 "warning: current architecture ($dpkgArch) does not have a corresponding Go binary release; will be building from source"; echo >&2 ;;  esac;   url="https://golang.org/dl/go${GOLANG_VERSION}.${goRelArch}.tar.gz";  wget -O go.tgz "$url";  echo "${goRelSha256} *go.tgz" | sha256sum -c -;  tar -C /usr/local -xzf go.tgz;  rm go.tgz;   if [ "$goRelArch" = 'src' ]; then   echo >&2;   echo >&2 'error: UNIMPLEMENTED';   echo >&2 'TODO install golang-any from jessie-backports for GOROOT_BOOTSTRAP (and uninstall after build)';   echo >&2;   exit 1;  fi;   export PATH="/usr/local/go/bin:$PATH";  go version   247MB               
/bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV GOLANG_VERSION=1.7.6                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              0B                  
/bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends   g++   gcc   libc6-dev   make   pkg-config  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      139MB               
/bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends   bzr   git   mercurial   openssh-client   subversion     procps  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 123MB               
/bin/sh -c set -ex;  if ! command -v gpg > /dev/null; then   apt-get update;   apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends    gnupg2    dirmngr   ;   rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*;  fi                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    0B                  
/bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends   ca-certificates   curl   wget  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  44.6MB              
/bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD ["bash"]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          0B                  
/bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:a023a99f7d01868b164d63bfaf8aabc7f271659c69939c3854f041f5a3217428 in /                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         123MB
```

I see them using apt-get so it is probably some kind of debian distribution.

What is the base distribution of this container? Is it ubuntu/alpine/... something else?

What does this mean?

```
/bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:a023a99f7d01868b164d63bfaf8aabc7f271659c69939c3854f041f5a3217428 in /                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         123MB
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The base image is `buildpack-deps:jessie-scm` based on [the Dockerfile here](https://github.com/docker-library/golang/blob/64b88dc3e9d83e71eafc000fed1f0d5e289b3e65/1.7/Dockerfile). So the linux distro is Debian Jessie.

The `ADD file: ...` line shows that the first layer in the image was created by adding some files from outside the image (similar to "COPY" shown in the other layers)

From [Dockerfile reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#add):

> The ADD instruction copies new files, directories or remote file URLs from  and adds them to the filesystem of the image at the path

Comment: Thanks @JamesJJ. Why is FROM missing from the output of docker history?

Comment: `FROM` does not actually do anything to change a layer or image metadata. It just means start this new image using these existing layers/metadata, so it doesn't show in `docker history`.  If you want to record the value of `FROM` in your image as e.g. a `LABEL`, then you can move the value of FROM to a build argument default, like this: https://gist.github.com/JamesJJ/224077352aa35642d9a2a4a4dabef44f